# AngularJS: Date as string to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I receive a date as string in this format "27/02/2018 09:00" How can I pass this to milliseconds? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to do this in a contoller/service or view?

Comment: In a controller

Answer (score 0):

You could use DatePipe from `@angular/common` 
module. It should make a trick. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of another way to do it (using the built in date filter) so just a raw js solution just using `split` and `Date`:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
    // new app  
  angular.module('myApp', []);

    // new controller
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MyController($scope) {
    var my_date = "27/02/2018 09:00";
    var parts = my_date.split(' ');
    var date_parts = parts[0].split('/');
    var time_parts = parts[1].split(':');
    var date_obj = new Date(date_parts[2], date_parts[1], date_parts[0], time_parts[0], time_parts[1]);
    $scope.milliseconds = date_obj.getTime();
  }

})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/19161/